# Calling a function on UTC time

Tags: javascript, utc

What I want to do is "to call a function every 4 hours based on UTC time not client side time.

```
function callFunction(){
    var date= new Date();
    date.setUTCHours(4);
}

if (time){   
    callFunction();
}

/* ----*/

else{
    //I do some stuff!
}
```

Comment: You identified a goal, but gave no problem statement regarding achieving your goal. Suggest you take a few minutes to read through [ask] and [Question checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist)

Comment: I don't know how to call the function every 4 hour?

Comment: use an interval timer to check time since last call or if minutes are zero and hour is 0 or divisible by 4

Comment: How do you want to call the function every 4 hours exactly? because using JavaScript, a browser should be opened and this specific page also should be open on that browser all the time! is it really what you are looking for?!

Comment: <script>

var d=new Date();
var ourT=d.getUTCMilliseconds();
var T=ourT*12;
setInterval(function(){console.log("pong");},T);
</script>

Comment: but its not running correctly sometimes after 12 seconds sometimes 5!  all I want is when to refresh my browser it should run on UTC system not renew the time frame every time I refresh it should be using Universal time not waiting for me to reload it and start over